# What is the correct spelling: "wrapable" or "wrappable"?

Tags: orthography, doubled-consonants

As it sounds: is "wrapable" correct, or is "wrappable" correct? Or are neither correct?

Microsoft Word complains about both, but Google doesn't correct either one.

Comment: @Mitch I think that such obviously off-topic questions are better left for dead rather than exhumed. It only encourages me to downvote everything in sight.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Wrappable.**  ([Google Ngrams data](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wrapable%2Cwrappable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwrappable%3B%2Cc0).)

A more common example, closely analogous to *wrappable*, is *slappable*.

Generally, when a short vowel (like the *a* of *wrap*) occurs in the last syllable of a verb, the consonant following it gets doubled in conjugated forms: thus *wrap* -> *wrapping*, *wrapped*, and so on; similarly, *fit* -> *fitting*, *fitted*, …

Conjugated forms with single consonants usually come from verbs ending with a long vowel and silent *e*.  So *rapping* comes from *rap*, but *raping* comes from *rape*; *bidding* comes from *bid*, but *biding* from *bide*.

Comment: Referring to the conjugated forms was a good idea.

Comment: @PPL: Truly an elegant answer. I'm impressed by the balance of breadth and the brevity.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think "wrappable" is a word that is in most standard spelling dictionaries, so that's probably why you're not getting an appropriate correction.  If it is a word, I would spell it with two ps.  Only one p would make the vowel long, I think, so it would sound more like rape-able.  Two ps would keep the vowel short.

Comment: +1 : "Two ps would keep the vowel short" and "one p would make the vowel long".

Comment: @Kit: So if your partner says your birthday present isn't *wrappable*, you'd have no idea what they meant? Me, I'd be hoping for either a sports car or a night of red-hot sex. Anyway, Google gives thousands of hits for even **"wrappable tripod"**, so it must be "a word".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm. Is it in the OED? Did Umberto Eco use it? I would be more convinced by that than "It's on the Internet, so it must be true."  After all, you can find "slarg" and "blijing" on the Internet, too.  But that said, of course "wrappable" is a word.  Let me edit that...

Comment: @Kit: The Official Scrabble Wordlist, based on Chambers dictionary, always contains at least some words (formed by standard inflections of other entries) that don't actually appear in that dictionary. I just checked my 1994 copy of OSW and *wrappable* isn't there, but I expect it's either already in the latest edition, or it will be in the next. Anyway, even if it's not really 'a word' by some definitions, at least we all know how to spell it!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would only accept OSW as a source if it agreed with me. Otherwise, I consider it to be a repository of words that were concocted by Scrabble players just so they could win games, which to me does not count as English. :P

Comment: @Kit: Well Chambers is quite respected, and it's the *reference dictionary* for one of UK's hardest crosswords (Sunday Times Mephisto). But like many, it doesn't necessarily *print* trivial regular extensions (lots of plurals, for example). Mind you, I was very annoyed to be denied **BI** a few years back. Turns out that one's in current editions; we were just using an old edition of OSW.