# Why is shippable spelled with 2 p's

Tags: orthography, doubled-consonants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct spelling: wrapable, or wrappable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26158/what-is-the-correct-spelling-wrapable-or-wrappable)

My mother "corrected" me and said "shouldn't shippable be spelled as shipable"? My gut feeling said two p's, but I couldn't think of a reason why. So I googled it and it is spelled with two p's, but I still don't know why. As far as I am concerned it could just as well be spelled with one 'p'.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4791/1547

Comment: We write *shipping*, *shipped* and *shipper*, right?  So, *shippable*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule, from the related questions, is: when adding a tense suffix other than "-s", like "-ing", "-ed", "-able", etc, you should double the ending consonant when the last syllable of the word ends in a single consonant, and that syllable is stressed. So, "ship", being a single syllable, is stressed, and it ends in a single consonant (instead of a double like ch, ss, ng, ck, nt, etc), so double it.